# How to create a MIDI connection between applications?

Tags: music, midi

I have been some trouble using applications that require MIDI like GuitarPro6 and tuxguitar.

These both programs make use of MIDI synthesis. However, I can only listen the midi output when I actually export the files I am working on and can't listen anything when I am just inputting notes as I should.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Most applications won't connect their MIDI output to any synthesizer/soundfont you use (same for the MIDI input). That means you will need to instruct the system where it should pass the MIDI data from tuxguitar, GuitarPro6 or anything else. **The simpliest way to connect MIDI inputs/outputs** is to use `aconnect` tool - it has GUI frontends `aconnectgui` and `kaconnect` (or `patchage` for larger setups with multiple apps). They are very simple to use and I am sure you will understand them - just connect your apps output to some MIDI synthesizer's (or timidity++, if you use it) input :)
Let me know in case of any problems.